# PHP Echo ipv4 and Ipv6

Tags: php, ip

How Do I make it so my script echo's both IPv4 And IPv6, but if 1 of them is not detected it will say ''Not Detected''.

```
<?php
echo 'IPv4 '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
?>
```

Comment: There's only one remote address. If the client used IPv4, it will be a v4 address. If the client used IPv6, it will be a v6 address.

Comment: The server can't get other addresses of the client machine, you can only get the address used for this connection.

Comment: How did https://whatismyipaddress.com do it then? They can detect both

Comment: It uses JavaScript to make multiple connections to the server, one to the server's IPv4 address and another to its IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one address, IPv4 or IPv6. You can detect using the filter extension

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) {
       echo "IPv6 detected";
 }
else {
      echo "IPv4";
}
```